# processing the blue value of an image

Tags: java, image-processing

image consists of three colors  RGB .. !! whether can take the blue color pixel values of the image and then do the process .. !! after blue pixel values transformation , then displayed back into an image with a blue value different from the previous image

Comment: .... so what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking up [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).

Of interest to you will be:

- [`getRGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-)
- [`setRGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB-int-int-int-)

> **`public int getRGB(int x, int y)`**
>
> Returns an integer pixel in the default RGB color model (`TYPE_INT_ARGB`) and default sRGB colorspace. Color conversion takes place if this default model does not match the image `ColorModel`. There are only 8-bits of precision for each color component in the returned data when using this method.

To obtain a `BufferedImage`, you can use [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html).